# Get all executed stored procedures in last 24 hours

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to find all the stored procedures that have been executed in last 24 hours? I need to show:

- time of the execution for the current stored procedure
- whole text of the stored procedures

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have edited my question. I will be happy if I am able to show only these two columns!

Comment: Have you implemented any form of logging within your stored procedures?

Comment: No, I haven't implemented

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Ok, but is there some way to return the whole stored procedure and when I send it as .txt file to be well formatted(to be able to see the whole procedure, not only some part of it). This will be enough too?

Comment: In real time, you can use a trace route but I'd be careful doing this since it's expensive. Be sure to limit the trace to just your username, or whoever's you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the sys tables might be helpful...

```
select o.name, eps.last_execution_time
  from [sys].[dm_exec_procedure_stats] eps
  join [sys].[objects] o ON eps.object_id = o.object_id
  where last_execution_time >= dateadd(HH, -24, getdate())
```

Comment: Of course this has to be extended if required, e.g. you can add the schema name via join...

Comment: I tried with this sys tables 2 days and still cannot find the best way to do this! But thank you for your respond!

Comment: Which additional Info do you need? What is missing in this query's result?

Comment: This won't show parameters and it only shows the last execution time in the last 24 hours (so if it's called 100 times, it won't show that).  Still, a handy query...

Comment: @AdamPlocher yes, 24 hours - as requested in the OP ;-)

Comment: He didn't request "Last" time a stored procedure was executed in the last 24 hours.  He said "all" stored procedures executed in 24 hours.  I guess he marked this as the answer, but it doesn't seem like the same thing he's asking for.

Comment: He also requested the full text of the stored procedure which your answer doesn't provide.  IMO this answer didn't answer any of his questions.